# Rails render issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok, another annoying problem.

I have a GuestsController that with an index action like this:

```
def index
  @booking = Booking.find(session[:booking_id]) #i have also hard coded values to make sure the session isn't the issue
  @guest = Guest.find(session[:guest_id])
end
```

and a personal action (to perform updates) as follows:

```
def personal
  @guest = Guest.find(session[:guest_id])
  if @guest.update(post_params)
    redirect_to :controller => 'guests', :action => 'cards'
  else
    render 'index'
  end
end
```

My index.html.erb view uses the @booking variable:

```
<%= @booking.friendly_id %> #this is one example
```

and also contains the form to submit the "name" field to the personal action. It updates fine if the data is valid but the @booking variable doesn't exist if it's invalid???

I need to show validation errors so I can't just use redirect_to.

The error I get is: **NoMethodError in Guests#personal** and **undefined method `friendly_id' for nil:NilClass**

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but `@booking` seems to be nil sometimes correct? Does `session[:booking_id]` always contain valid data to supply the to the query?

Comment: Well I tested for that by hard coding a booking id and still the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize the object in else part

```
  else
    @booking = Booking.find(session[:booking_id])
    render 'index'
  end
```

Comment: But shouldn't the @booking be picked up when the index gets rendered?

Comment: No, `render 'index'` will just render the `index` view, it will not execute `render` action

Answer (score 1):

How about moving `@booking` and `@guest` definitions to before_filter?

```
before_filter do
  @booking = Booking.find(session[:booking_id]) #i have also hard coded values to make sure the session isn't the issue
  @guest = Guest.find(session[:guest_id])
end
```

Comment: I'm rails 4 so before_action i guess - this is a possibility but I'm unsure why booking would be nil as the session doesn't disappear?

Comment: Every request user sends causes Rails to instantiate new controller instance. Hence when variable was defined in one action, it is not defined on the controller serving other action.

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be something to handle when `@booking` is `nil` - which can happen if I'm reading this right.

```
def index
  if Booking.find(session[:booking_id])?
    @booking = Booking.find(session[:booking_id])
  else
    @booking = Booking.build #or whatever you want here
  end 
  @guest = Guest.find(session[:guest_id])
end
```

Comment: @booking should never be nil as it's based on the session and no where do I actually delete this session. So that's what is confusing me a little